# Integral of Meijer G-function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration

I am trying to integrate this:

$$\int_0^\infty \log(1+x^r)x^{a-1}e^{-\beta x}I_v(kx) \ \mathrm dx$$
where $r, a, \beta, v, k$ are arbitrary constants, $v$ is the order of the modified bessel function of the first kind and $r\leq 1$.

I found a possible way to work it out using Meijer G-function, which is by transforming the logarithm, the exponential and the Bessel function to their equivalent [Meijer G-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function) form, [which could be integrated in mathematica](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/21/ShowAll.html).

However, I don't know how to deal with Meijer G-function in Mathematica.
please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may find examples at [Wolfram](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeijerG.html) directly.

Alpha may return an answer as [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BMeijerG%5B%7B%7B%7D,%20%7B2%7D%7D,%20%7B%7B1/2,%203/2%7D,%20%7B%7D%7D,%203%5D,%2050%5D) for the numerical evaluation of :

[image: representation]

Note that the terms between $G$ and '$($' in $G^{m,n}_{p,q}$ allow to count the elements at the second level and will appear only 'implicitly', the term between '$($' and '$|$' is the $z$ from $z^{-s}$ ($3$ here) and must be put alone at the right of the function.
In the required syntax for MeijerG the first parameters will be written $\{\{a_l\},\{a_r\}\}$ corresponding to the high part at the right of the representation (with $a_l$ constituted of $n$ parameters separated by ',' ).
The second parameter will be $\{\{b_l\},\{b_r\}\}$ for the low part with $b_l$ constituted of $m$ parameters to give something like :

> MeijerG[{{}, {2}}, {{1/2, 3/2}, {}}, 3]

Alpha will also often produce 'Time-out'...